# SoapUI, xml namespaces & SAP B1

Tags: xml, soap, soapui

I have two parts of question. First one is about xml standard, second one about workaround for SoapUI.
I have wsdl scheme for SAP B1 DI server (it actually does not matter. I mean any third party SOAP service). I have SOAP request, generated by SoapUI

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:dis="http://www.sap.com/SBO/DIS" 
xmlns:bus="BusinessPartnersService">
<soapenv:Header>
  <dis:MsgHeader>
     <dis:SessionID>?</dis:SessionID>
     <dis:ServiceName>BusinessPartnersService</dis:ServiceName>
  </dis:MsgHeader>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
  <bus:Add>
     <dis:BusinessPartner>
        <dis:CardCode>?</dis:CardCode>
...
...
```

My question about this line

```
<dis:CardCode>?</dis:CardCode>
```

In this form it does not work (DI server returns error). Working line is

```
<CardCode>?</CardCode>
```

I.e. without namespace specification. 
So my first question: does it match any xml standard?

And second question: how can I tell SoapUI to skip namespace?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the service provider if there is conflict with namespace?

Comment: Ok I bet you the error says something like invalid parameter or value. If you are send the `?` as a value inyour request it is going to create a problem. It would appear that CardCode is a number and you are sending a `?` as a value. The XML is very valid both of them. If they are correct that is a different matter. Try the following `<dis:CardCode></dis:CardCode>`